# PHP redirect within $okMessage

Tags: php, forms, redirect, refresh, contacts

I have recently encountered a problem where i am using PHP and all of my nice files are kept in HTML, my PHP contact form works and it sends it however it opens up the PHP document upon sending, i understand the obvious answer to rredirect back to a new HTML page would be a PHP redirect however i wanted it to only redirect upon it sending properly . I.E instead of a success message and it to redirect to another page if the email fails to send. I cant seem to find any help online for this. I have added the entire document below and would love any kind of help you could offer.

```
 <?php
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=contact2.html" /
// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <Contact@gmail.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <tomwilkinson104@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

//sending 

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: The immediate answer is: you should send different location headers, so that different redirections occur.

Comment: The most likely better approach however would be to trigger this script by a ajax request (so by means of javascript instead of a form submission). That way your _client side logic_ (javascript) can decide what to do, based on the content of the json result sent by the php script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by

> error_reporting(0); error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

```
try
{
    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
```